# How can I export my Datagrid to Excel File

Tags: excel, wpf, datagrid

I want to Export from my Datagrid all columns and rows to an Excel File.But I haven't an experience especially about this transformation.I want to learn this topic deep and maybe someones could help to my Codes how to design in a WPF Application.

Here is my Datagrid in XAML Format and I'm using as dB Northwind.

```
<Border Grid.ColumnSpan="3">
            <DataGrid x:Name="datagridbindings" Foreground="Black" IsReadOnly="True" CanUserResizeColumns="False" CanUserResizeRows="False" FontWeight="SemiBold" HeadersVisibility="Column" HorizontalGridLinesBrush="Blue" VerticalGridLinesBrush="White" AutoGenerateColumns="False">

                <DataGrid.Columns>
                    <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Company ID" >
                        <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                            <ItemContainerTemplate>
                                <TextBlock  Style="{StaticResource textblock}" x:Name="customername" Text="{Binding MusteriID}"/>
                            </ItemContainerTemplate>
                        </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                    </DataGridTemplateColumn>


                    <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Company Name" >
                        <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate >
                            <ItemContainerTemplate >
                                <TextBlock Style="{StaticResource textblock}" x:Name="categoryname" Text="{Binding FirmaAdi}"/>
                            </ItemContainerTemplate>
                        </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                    </DataGridTemplateColumn>


                    <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Contact Name" >
                        <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                            <ItemContainerTemplate >
                                <TextBlock Style="{StaticResource textblock}" Width="auto" x:Name="tanim" Text="{Binding SorumluKisi}"/>
                            </ItemContainerTemplate>
                        </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                    </DataGridTemplateColumn>

                    <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Contact Title" >
                        <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                            <ItemContainerTemplate >
                                <TextBlock  x:Name="picture" Text="{Binding Yetkisi}"/>
                            </ItemContainerTemplate>
                        </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                    </DataGridTemplateColumn>

                    <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Address" >
                        <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                            <ItemContainerTemplate >
                                <TextBlock  x:Name="picture" Text="{Binding Adres}"/>
                            </ItemContainerTemplate>
                        </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                    </DataGridTemplateColumn>

                    <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="City" >
                        <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                            <ItemContainerTemplate >
                                <TextBlock  x:Name="picture" Text="{Binding Sehir}"/>
                            </ItemContainerTemplate>
                        </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                    </DataGridTemplateColumn>





                    <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Country" >
                        <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                            <ItemContainerTemplate >
                                <TextBlock  x:Name="picture" Text="{Binding Ulke}"/>
                            </ItemContainerTemplate>
                        </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                    </DataGridTemplateColumn>

                    <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Phone" >
                        <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                            <ItemContainerTemplate >
                                <TextBlock  x:Name="picture" Text="{Binding TelefonNo}"/>
                            </ItemContainerTemplate>
                        </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                    </DataGridTemplateColumn>

                    <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Region" >
                        <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                            <ItemContainerTemplate >
                                <TextBlock  x:Name="picture" Text="{Binding Bolge}"/>
                            </ItemContainerTemplate>
                        </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                    </DataGridTemplateColumn>

                    <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Postal Code" >
                        <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                            <ItemContainerTemplate >
                                <TextBlock  x:Name="picture" Text="{Binding PostaKodu}"/>
                            </ItemContainerTemplate>
                        </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                    </DataGridTemplateColumn>

                    <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Fax No" >
                        <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                            <ItemContainerTemplate >
                                <TextBlock  x:Name="picture" Text="{Binding FaxNo}"/>
                            </ItemContainerTemplate>
                        </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                    </DataGridTemplateColumn>

                </DataGrid.Columns>
            </DataGrid>
        </Border>
```

And here is the my Customer Class in CS Format

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Data;
using System.Windows.Documents;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;
using System.Windows.Navigation;
using System.Windows.Shapes;
using WpfDropDownNavigate;
using WpfDropDownNavigate.Business;
using WpfDropDownNavigate.Models;
using Excel = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.OleDb;



namespace MenuWithSubMenu.Pages
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for Profile.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class Customers : Page
    {


        public Customers()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            
        }

        //Bring Customers
void MusterileriGetir()
        {
            try
            {
                datagridbindings.ItemsSource = MusteriBusiness.MusterileriGetir();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {

                MessageBox.Show("Tables Cannot Received! " + ex.Message, "Fail", MessageBoxButton.OK, MessageBoxImage.Error);
            }
        }


        private void Page_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            MusterileriGetir();
        }

        
        //add new Record!
        private void record_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            Musteriler seciliMusteri = datagridbindings.SelectedItem as Musteriler;
            try
            {
                MessageBoxResult m = MessageBox.Show("Are you sure to Update? ", "Confirmation!", MessageBoxButton.OKCancel, MessageBoxImage.Question);
                if (m == MessageBoxResult.Cancel)
                {
                    seciliMusteri = null;
                }
                else
                {
                    MusteriBusiness.MusteriGuncelle(txtcompanyname.Text, txtcontactname.Text, txtcontacttitle.Text, txtadress.Text, txtcity.Text, txtregion.Text, txtpostalcode.Text, txtcountry.Text, txtphone.Text, txtfax.Text, seciliMusteri.MusteriID);
                    MessageBox.Show("Updated!", "Info", MessageBoxButton.OK, MessageBoxImage.Information);
                }


            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {

                MessageBox.Show("Tables Cannot Received! " + ex.Message, "Fail", MessageBoxButton.OK, MessageBoxImage.Error);
            }
        }

        private void Close()
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }

        private void newselect_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            new addnewcustomer().ShowDialog();
        }

        private void delete_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            Musteriler seciliMusteri = datagridbindings.SelectedItem as Musteriler;
            try
            {
                MessageBoxResult m = MessageBox.Show("Are you sure to Delete? ", "Confirmation!", MessageBoxButton.OKCancel, MessageBoxImage.Question);
                if (m == MessageBoxResult.Cancel)
                {
                    seciliMusteri = null;
                }
                else
                {
                    int seciliSatirNo = datagridbindings.SelectedIndex;
                    MusteriBusiness.MusteriSil(seciliMusteri.MusteriID);
                    MusterileriGetir();
                    datagridbindings.SelectedIndex = seciliSatirNo;
                    MessageBox.Show("Deleted!", "Info", MessageBoxButton.OK, MessageBoxImage.Information);
                }




            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {

                MessageBox.Show("Tables Cannot Received! " + ex.Message, "Fail", MessageBoxButton.OK, MessageBoxImage.Error);
            }
        }

        private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            //If I click this Button,I want to convert my datagrid to excel format.

        }
    }


}
```

Comment: Problem Solved!

Answer (score 0):

I have done just that couple of days ago, via this video tutorial.
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7oTcMeSMjO8 It worked for me, hope it will for you too.

In case link expires or something, here are the steps.

1. First you need to Add Reference to your project called Microsoft Excel 16.0 Object Library.
2. Then add those two lines

using Excel = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel;

using Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel;

3. After implementing "Excel.Window" Interface, you need to do the same
   by implementing Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Window (both will be suggested under the MainWindow: ***Window*** interface).
4. Then here is the final code for your button

private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)

```
        {
            Excel.Application excel = new Excel.Application();

            excel.Visible = true; 
            Workbook workbook = excel.Workbooks.Add(System.Reflection.Missing.Value);
            Worksheet sheet1 = (Worksheet)workbook.Sheets[1];
 
            for (int j = 0; j < dgrid.Columns.Count; j++)  
            {
                Range myRange = (Range)sheet1.Cells[1, j + 1];
                sheet1.Cells[1, j + 1].Font.Bold = true; 
                sheet1.Columns[j + 1].ColumnWidth = 15; 
                myRange.Value2 = dgrid.Columns[j].Header;
            }
            for (int i = 0; i < dgrid.Columns.Count; i++)
            { 
                for (int j = 0; j < dgrid.Items.Count; j++)
                {
                    TextBlock b = dgrid.Columns[i].GetCellContent(dgrid.Items[j]) as TextBlock;
                    Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Range myRange = (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Range)sheet1.Cells[j + 2, i + 1];
                    myRange.Value2 = b.Text;
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: I used these codes but it didn't work in my case.Because I'm using Pages instead of  a Window.If I want to implement interface of these codes  it shows me a Problem.Thank you for your Answer.

Comment: Oh, okay. Glad you found the way anyhow.

Comment: You are right, my answer is edited. Thanks